# Django admin login broken when using apache wsgi

Tags: django

I am facing an interesting problem where I'm unable to login to the admin page of my app when I access it through wsgi in apache.

However when I try to access it through the django dev server it works just fine.

I don't get a wrong login warning I just see an get redirected to the same page as if nothing happened. Putting in wrong credentials does prompt that I have put in wrong credentials.

The only difference between dev server and the apache should be the I'm using virtualenv when creating the django dev server.

I've made sure to remove the standard paths from the sys.path and make it identical to when the virtual env is invoked.

I'm not seeing anything in the apache logs either.

Thanks!

Comment: Try running the dev server in your production environment and see what happens when you access it on :8000.

Comment: running on the dev server works fine.